# Compile error when calling managed C++ from C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am new to .net .
I have a managed C++ library. It looks like this.

```
// header file
namespace cppnetdll
{
public __gc class Class1
{
public:
static int foo_int(void);
};
}

// source file
namespace cppnetdll
{
int Class1::foo_int(void)
{
return 123;
}
}
```

I can call this from a managed c++ program. When I try to call it from
a C# program, I get the compiler error: "The type or namespace name
'Class1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
assembly reference?)" The error refers to the DllImport line below.

Here is the C# code
    [code:1:a72c1df571]
    namespace csuser
    {
    public class xxx
    {
    [DllImport("cppnetdll.dll")] extern
    int Class1.foo_int();

```
private void yyy() { int i =
foo_int(); }
}
}[/code:1:a72c1df571]
```

I have tried various approaches but no success. What is the magic
syntax ?

It's funny that I can call unmanaged C++ functions from C# fairly
easily by declaring the functions as "C" and exporting from the DLL.
I expected calling managed code to be easier. Maybe it's so easy
that no one thought of documenting it !

Comment: You're new to .NET and using "Managed Extensions for C++"?  In 2011?  Get a newer version of Visual C++ (Visual Studio 2005 or newer will do) and start using C++/CLI.  There's only one thing to do with MC++ code: delete it wherever you find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use a [DllImport] directive to call code that's written in managed C++.  That is only intended for native DLLs that export their functions.  Neither of which applies to yours, it isn't native and you don't export the function.

You built a managed assembly, you can treat it just like one you'd have written in C#.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, navigate to the DLL.  Or better yet, put both projects in one solution, use the Projects tab to select the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the [DllImport ...]

Try just adding a reference, here is a how to from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx